# Check HTML element type and compare it

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a button that activates a function onClick, then I want to check all classes of my page with the id of this button. Then it should get the element Type and compare it to e.g. "icon". So if the element is an icon it should get a different style than a div.
I already have an approach but I am stuck:

HTML:

```
<div class="question-tile-container">
                 <button id="01" class="01 button" onClick="test(this)">
                            <p>How do I create an account?</p>
                            <i class="01 fa-regular fa-arrow-down-wide-short"></i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="01 answer">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JS:

```
function test(ele) {
    var id = ele.id
    console.log(id)

    elements = document.getElementsByClassName(id)
    console.log(elements)


    for(i=0;i<elements.length+1;i++){
        if(elements.tagName == 'icon') {
            // style icon
        } else {
            // style div
        }
    }
}
```

It should check all elements with the id, then compare the element type to a string. If it matches a specific string it should style in a different way, than it would if it matches to another string.

Comment: A class name cannot start with a number, so you have a problem here. Consider using data attribute. So it can be `<i data-index = "01" class="...>`. Another question how many tags can you have?  Only <i> and <div>? If yes, you can use `querySelectorAll("i[data-index=01]")` and `querySelectorAll("div[data-index=01]")` and there will be no need to check tag name.